# Merge multiple lists horizontally in python

Tags: python

I have two different lists like below

```
A = [(Apple, Mango)]
B = [Grapes]
```

Now I would like to get a merged list as follows

```
C = [(Apple,Mango,Grapes)]
```

Is there any predefined functions available in python to get above merged list.

Note: Already used zip method which is returning the result as different result

```
C = [(Apple,Mango),(Grapes)]
```

The snippet of code which returned above result is this

```
A = [('Apple','Mango')]
B = ['Grapes']

C = zip(A,B)

print C
```

Comment: What if `B` has more items? Are you looking to grow the first element of `A`?

Comment: I am iterating in a loop to grow the list A with the values of B

Comment: @Arun Please make your example valid code.

Comment: List `A` is a list of a tuple. Tuples are immutable and will produce a heavy overhead if applied like this. You may want to use simple lists (or lists of lists instead of lists of tuples.

Comment: @Arun in your example, you are growing the _first element_  of list `A`. That element is a tuple.

Comment: You can combine list comprehensions with the zip() function for a concise solution: ````C = [(a,b,c) for (a,b),c in zip(A,B)]````

Comment: @jbndlr A is list of tuples only and the expected result is also a list of tuples

Comment: @JanBöcker Thanks it worked

Comment: Your example is a bit to trivial to tell us what you expect in a more complicated situation. Can you show what you expect to happen if both `A` and `B` have more elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's an approach of flattening the tuple after the `zip`, it might perform less as for time complexity, but it will get what you want even for mixed type list, like `[str, tuple]` and `[tuple, str]`

```
a = [("apple", "mango"), "orange"]     # This is [tuple, str]
b = ["grapes", ("pineapple", "lemon")] # This one's [str, tuple]

flatten = ( lambda itr: sum(map(flatten, itr), tuple())
        if isinstance(itr, tuple) else (itr,)
         )

c = [flatten(x) for x in zip(a, b)]

print (c)
# [('apple', 'mango', 'grapes'), ('orange', 'pineapple', 'lemon')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If A is list of tuples and B is normal list, this works

```
A = [('Apple', 'Mango')]
B = ['Grapes']
print [ tuple( sum ( map(list,A), [] ) + B) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

For you example, you could do

```
C = list(A[0] + (B[0],))
```

Comment: @vishes_shell Thanks,  I did not notice that. Made the edit now.

Answer (score 0):

If A and B is list of tuples then you can be use following recursive function

**Input something like this**

```
A = [('Apple', 'Mango'), ('Mango1')]
B = [('Grapes', 'Banana'), ('Apple1')]
```

**Recursive function**

```
def recursive_fun(c, temp_list):
    for i in c:
        if type(i) is tuple:
            recursive_fun(list(i), temp_list)
        else :
            temp_list.append(i)
    return temp_list
```

**Output**

```
[tuple(recursive_fun(A, [])+ recursive_fun(B, []))]
```

**Final output**

```
[('Apple', 'Mango', 'Mango1', 'Grapes', 'Banana', 'Apple1')]
```

Comment: no need for recursion , you can simply unpack them with `*`, `x = (1, 2)` and `y = (3, 4)` then `(*x, *y)` would give `(1, 2, 3, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

Since tuples are not mutable, we can't append/add to `A[0]`. Let's just unpack and create a new tuple within a list:

`[(*A[0], *B)]`